# Getting A Server Error-What Does This Mean?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, stored-procedures

What does this error message mean I am doing wrong?

Server Error in '/' Application.

Procedure or function 'Campaign_ProcessClick_4' expects parameter '@UserAgent', which was not supplied.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Procedure or function 'Campaign_ProcessClick_4'
expects parameter '@UserAgent', which was not supplied.

Source Error:

```
         Line 164:                End If
         Line 165:                cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ip", 
         Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)).Value = Ip
         Line 166:                **cmdProcessClick.ExecuteNonQuery()**
         Line 167:                If cnn.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
         Line 168:                cnn.Close()
```

Here is the function

```
        Using cmdProcessClick As New SqlCommand(spToUse, cnn)
            cmdProcessClick.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@CampaignId", 
         Data.SqlDbType.Int)).Value = CampaignId
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LinkId", 
         Data.SqlDbType.Int)).Value = LinkId
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SubId", 
         Data.SqlDbType.TinyInt)).Value = SubId
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserAgent", Data.SqlDbType.Text)).Value = UserAgent

            If Trim(Len(Referrer)) > 0 Or Trim(Referrer) <> String.Empty Then
                cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Referrer", 
            Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = Referrer
            Else
                cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Referrer", 
             Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100)).Value = DBNull.Value
            End If
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Ip", 
           Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15)).Value = Ip
            cmdProcessClick.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Is UserAgent a required field in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL query likely has something along these lines:

```vb
SomeField = @UserAgent
```

But the @UserAgent is not being added as a parameter for the command.

You will need to do something similar to what you're doing with `@Id` prior to calling `ExecuteNonQuery`:

```vb
' optionally change the SqlDbType and length
' you must change MyUserAgentValue to an actual value 
cmdProcessClick.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@UserAgent", Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 64)).Value = MyUserAgentValue
```

Answer (score 0):

I simplified the code a bit by adding a `With...End With` statement. Also, if you pass the parameter name, type, and size directly to the `.Add` method, a parameter will be created. No need for `New Parameter`

You need to check if `Referrer` is null (`Nothing` in vb.net) first before you try to check the length of the string. Otherwise the dreaded NRE (Null Reference Exception). The `OrElse` short circuits the `If` statement so the second condition is never evaluated if the first is true.

I think the validation code should be performed in the calling code so the correct value will be passed to the Sub but I leave that to you. In this case, Nothing or a string value.

This code will fail in the calling code if a value for @UserAgent is not included.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Your connection string"

Private Sub UpdateDatabase(CampaignId As Integer, LinkId As Integer, SubId As Short, UserAgent As String, Referrer As String, Ip As String)
    Using cnn As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
        cmdProcessClick As New SqlCommand("spName", cnn)
        cmdProcessClick.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        With cmdProcessClick.Parameters
            .Add("@CampaignId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CampaignId
            .Add("@LinkId", SqlDbType.Int).Value = LinkId
            .Add("@SubId", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = SubId
            .Add("@UserAgent", SqlDbType.Text).Value = UserAgent
            If IsNothing(Referrer) OrElse Referrer.Trim.Length = 0 Then
                .Add("@Referrer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = DBNull.Value
            Else
                .Add("@Referrer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = Referrer
            End If
            .Add("@Ip", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15).Value = Ip
        End With
        If IsNothing(Referrer) OrElse Referrer.Trim.Length = 0 Then
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters("@Referrer").Value = Nothing
        Else
            cmdProcessClick.Parameters("@Referrer").Value = Referrer
        End If
        cmdProcessClick.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```